# how to render my custom web-part as soon as i insert on the page?

Tags: web-part

i have created a web-part that user will define the url to render and after user insert the web part on the page it did not renders, user have to edit and enter the url and click apply or ok button in the prop.

here is my code i am using...

```
string SiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;//Get the url of current site
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
                {
                    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                    SPFile webPartPage = web.GetFile(SPContext.Current.ListItemServerRelativeUrl);
                    SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = webPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    pvwp.Title = WebPart.WebPartTitle;
                    pvwp.Description = WebPart.WebPartDescription;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebPart.WebPartContentLink.ToString()))
                    {
                        pvwp.ContentLink = "http://www.cnn.com";
                    }

                    pvwp.Width = "10in";
                    pvwp.Height = "15in";

                    pvwp.ContentLink = WebPart.WebPartContentLink.ToString();
                    //webPartManager.AddWebPart(pvwp, "TOP", 0);
                    this.Controls.Add(pvwp); 
                }
```

Comment: just to clarify, where is this code running? is it in one of the webpart methods?

Comment: the code is running on the usercontrol code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the page viewer webpart to display in your webpart, just instantiate a new instance of the PageViewerWebPart object, set the properties with the value from the webpart property, and add it to the Controls for the webpart.

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class WebPart1 : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{

    private string _ViewerInformation = null;

    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    [WebBrowsable(true)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("PageViewer Filter")]
    [WebDisplayName("List with ViewerInformation")]
    [WebDescription("The list on the current site where the user information is stored.")]
    public string listWithViewerInformation
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ViewerInformation == null)
            {
                _ViewerInformation = string.Empty;
            }
            return _ViewerInformation ;
        }
        set { _ViewerInformation = value; }
    }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();
        pvwp.ContentLink = _ViewerInformation ;
        this.Controls.Add(pvwp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();`

Comment: Rich, i am doing that if you read my code `this.Controls.Add(pvwp); ` i am not sure i understand what you want to do...

Comment: So is the end goal is just to get a PageViewerWebpart onto your page?  The properties for this PVVWP are being set by the user in the webpart properties panel.

Comment: yes, the end goal is to display the website on the pageviewerwebpart. by default i am trying to set the website(cnn.com) but its not effecting when my insert my webpart.

Comment: answer updated based on these comments

Comment: i am lost what you saying...

Comment: If all you are doing is adding the out of the box PageViewerWebpart to your page, you can do this through the web page UI.  There is no need for custom development.

Comment: i am not sure if you understood what i am trying to do... what i am doing is that i am using PageviewerWebPart control to show any website where user provide the url through custom prop which i have created...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1263/discussion-between-rich-ross-and-abu-hamzah)